# Windows 10 UWP App - Main screen does not refresh, I'm using Template 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml, template10

I am stuck with a strange issue and haven spent hours... Please help..

I am developing an app, that basically fetches some data from a Web service and displays on a Main Page - which has 3 text blocks.
I am using Template 10 - Minimal template. App compiles and runs smoothly.

The issue occurs as follows : 
Step 1 : User opens the app, view content. Presses BACK button (of windows mobile) to go back. App Closes. Fine.

Step 2 : A Push notification comes which updates the content.

Step 3 : When user opens app again, he sees the same old content from Step 1.

It is very strange. I have checked the bindings and everything is fine. 
It seems when the user starts the app in Step 3, the OS simply activates the UI. 
It does not refresh the UI as per new data.

I have done the following coding:

In the App.xaml.cs file : In the method : OnStartAsync - I am getting the instance of the MainPageViewModel.cs and calling a method that SETS new values of the data binding attributes. 
It still does not work.

Strangely - In debugging it works. When I disconnect the debugger and test on device, it DOES NOT :(

I am also OK with a dirty solution..

Can someone also suggest a way - How can I clear the APP or Kill the App OR clear the navigation history when the user presses BACK button in Step 1. 
I am assuming if I clear the navigation history, then the app will reinitialize (as in recreate the MainPage) and everything will be fine...

Please help.

Comment: What are you binding to? Did you raise the Property Changed Event for the properties whose values changed? Can you post the relevant code from your project?

Comment: Code or reproduce project please.  ` When user opens app again`, how the user open the app, from notification or other?

Comment: Suspect activation from Notification is part of the issue since if app is already running then a notification activation is slightly different than a standard run from start/taskbar.

Comment: When debugging your app never fully gets suspended, but when in release mode being triggered from the push notification your app will be resumed with the same state usually as when it was suspended, in the OnActivated event you need to handle the push notification to trigger the loading of that content, fetch the new content or get it from wherever your notification got it from, this may help

Answer (score 0):

It seems your view does not update when the model is updated. You should use an MVVM approach for updating the view on the go.

If you want to update a list in your view.

instead of `List <element>` use `ObservableCollection<element>`

Hope this help. If not you have to post your code to be able to answer.